# Make an ItemsControl which is wider than the available space always show the last items (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a horizontally oriented* ItemsControl inside a fixed width grid cell, and due to the number of items, it won't all fit inside that cell. It's fine if the content gets cut off, but rather than showing the first few elements until it runs out of space, I want the *last* few elements to be visible (i.e. I want it to overflow to the left and cut off the leftmost elements instead of the rightmost). I've tried setting horizontal alignment and/or content horizontal alignment to right, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

(*) By which I mean:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfThings}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         ...
    </ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Right` on the StackPanel in the ItemsPanel:

```
<ItemsControl ...>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thank you very much. I was changing the HorizontalAlignment of the ItemsControl...